# How to concatenate duplicate rows in Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

From the original data, there are duplicated data. The duplicates with different DB have to concat to the back of the former one.Is there any way to merge two tables into one as shown below by comparing between data? Are there any way of picking out those with only same title and other columns are all different?

From the original data using drop.duplicates and duplicated, i get two tables by masking different DB but duplicated in other columns and wanted to compare them using dictionaries, but by making rows as dictionaries in both the table, the keys are the same in every dictionary which i can't merge them together.

This is the original data given

```
  DB TITLE  ISSN  IBSN
0  M     a     1   NaN
1  M     d     1   NaN
2  M     c     1   NaN
3  N     b     1   NaN
4  N     a     1   NaN
5  N     d     1   NaN
6  O     c     1   NaN
7  O     e     1   NaN
8  O     a     1   NaN
9  O     b     1   NaN
10 M     a     2     2
11 N     a     2   NaN
```

By using drop_duplicates and duplicated:

```
>>>df1=df.drop_duplicates(['TITLE','ISSN','IBSN'])
>>>index=df.duplicated(['TITLE','ISSN','IBSN'])
>>>df2=df[index]
  DB TITLE  ISSN  IBSN             DB TITLE  ISSN  IBSN        
0  M     a     1   NaN           0  N     a     1   NaN        
1  M     d     1   NaN           1  N     d     1   NaN         
2  M     c     1   NaN           2  O     c     1   NaN       
3  M     a     2     2           3  O     a     1   NaN
4  N     a     2   NaN           4  O     b     1   NaN   
5  N     b     1   NaN           
6  O     e     1   NaN
        df1                               df2
```

This is the kind of dictionary i get from the rows:

```
{'DB': 'N', 'TITLE': 'a', 'ISSN': 1, 'IBSN': 'NaN'}
{'DB': 'M', 'TITLE': 'a', 'ISSN': 1, 'IBSN': 'NaN'}
```

I expect the output to be

```
    DB TITLE  ISSN  IBSN   DB TITLE  ISSN ISBN   DB TITLE  ISSN  IBSN
0    M     a   1.0   NaN    N     a   1.0  NaN    O     a   1.0   NaN
1    N     b   1.0   NaN    O     b   1.0  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2    M     d   1.0   NaN    N     d   1.0  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3    M     c   1.0   NaN    O     c   1.0  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4    O     e   1.0   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5    M     a   2.0   2.0  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
6    N     a   2.0   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

The order of 'TITLE' in the column is not important but the 'DB' have to be sorted alphabetically from left to right and null are always at the last.

Comment: You can not have the same column names in pandas, thus your expected output is not possible.

Comment: ```df.sort_values(by  = ['ISSN','TITLE'])```  You can do the previous code to order the df the way you want, but not quite in the same format.